# Final declaration '?' character is not shown in string where is the problem?

Tags: flutter, dart, text, final

**Declaration:**

```
static final String LoginForgotPassword="Forgot Password?";
```

**Use:**

```
Text(DefaultTexts.LoginForgotPassword)
```

**Result:**

[image]

**But it work:**

```
Text(DefaultTexts.LoginForgotPassword+"?")
```

Comment: did you try this? static final String LoginForgotPassword="Forgot Password\?";

Comment: i tried now and it worked thanks.

Comment: I think the issue is more complicated than an escape character. It seems you solved the problem but I still want to see your design of the code. I tried to get the error with your first usage, but it also worked for me.

Comment: You can look my Login Page View on github [repo](https://github.com/mwlt68/Login-and-register-pages-UI-design)